# I have client (React) and server(Node/Express) in separate repos, how to use Docker Compose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have client and server separated in two different repos. I cannot join them in a monorepo.

If I make a Dockerfile in each repo how can I use them together?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep them in separate repos, then `docker build` both repos locally, optionally `docker push`, then use `docker compose` or other container orchestration tools to run both together at the same time.